# Java script: object not defined error, after using object.create to create object

Tags: javascript

After creating an object using Object.create, I get an 'object not defined' error.

The object is defined ok and displays a sprite on the screen. But when later I try to access this object I get the error. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be grateful.

I'm creating the object in one function and trying reference it in another...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see any problems in the code _you don't show..._ Please click "edit" and add the troublesome code to your question. (From your mention of different functions this sounds like a scope problem, but really we need to see your code.)

Comment: Also you didn't show any code I guess you pretty much answer the question yourself: `I'm creating the object in one function and trying reference it in another...` read something about `scopes`.

Comment: Try new Object(); instead